# Filling missing data in a data set

Tags: matlab, dataset, interpolation

I have a data set like the following:

```
x= [1, 4, 10]
y= [10, 20, 30]
```

(`x` and `y` are value pairs, i.e. `(1,10), (4,20), (10,30)`)

I would like to fill the `x` values gaps and get linear interpolated values for `y`. The linear interpolation should be done between each value pair, i.e. between `(1,10)` and `(4,20)` and then again between `(4,20)` and `(10,30)`.

```
x= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y= [10,?, ?, 20, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 30]
```

How can I solve this with MATLAB?
Regards,
Dennis

**P.S.** My original data set has over 300 value pairs...

Answer (score 1):

Using [`interp1`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)

**Code:**

```
x= [1, 4, 10];
y= [10, 20, 30];
xi = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
yi = interp1(x,y,xi);
```

**Results:**

```
>> yi

yi =

  10    13.333   16.667    20    21.667    23.333    25    26.667   28.333     30
```

**Graphical Output** using `plot(xi,yi,'-*')`

[image]