# Resample 2 vector array in Matlab and output in same dimension

Tags: matlab, interpolation, linear-interpolation

How can I resample my `[t x]` matrix and fill the gap of resampled data with interpolation data in Matlab?

Input is the upper signal output is lower signal in the image.The output should be `[tout xout]` with similar dimensions to `[t x]`. The middle points of resampled data should be interpolated.

Here is a visualisation of my desired output:

[image: Image of Desired output]
[image: Image of Data and desired output]

```
t = [0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 0.5]                                                   % Original Time Vector
x = [1 2 2.5 2.4 3 2 1]                                                   % Original Data Vector
L = length(t);
tv = linspace(min(t), max(t), L);                             % Time Vector For Interpolation
dv = interp1(t, x, tv, 'linear');                             % Interpolated Data Vector
Ts = mean(diff(tv));
```

Comment: Read about interp1, fillgaps.

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: The code doesn't  include resampling

Comment: You can use [`randsample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) or [`datasample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/datasample.html) if you have the Statistics toolbox.  Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53524024/8239061) with full reproducible example for [`interp1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html).  See [Filling missing data in a dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29591624/8239061) for another example.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54859855/8239061) for how to randomly sample from original data (multiple options).

Comment: can u help me write a code for that? I  know how to do it in one dimention but resampling and interpolation between x and y vector is a bit hard.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you looked at these reproducible examples and the documentation links (which also have examples)?  What part are you struggling with?

Comment: yes i looked but examples pertain to using randsample in 1 column matrix only. I have both time (t) and (x)  data. if I want to resample at 0.03 second then i should get the equivalent x value in the same row.

Comment: @JomerSenorin I have the impression you dont understand interpolation / resampling. Take your time to read the links which SecretAgentMan posted and apply them to your data. You will profit from this by far more than just getting code which you dont understand

Comment: i understand my problem correctly. just like what i said before my data has t and x column。Maybe you can answer with code and explain it?

Comment: @JomerSenorin A *small* numerical example showing the output of your current approach and your desired output would probably be helpful at this point.

Comment: I added numerical example please check. Thanks

Comment: Add data as data, not images. You've shown you understand how to include text formatted as code, include your [mcve] the same...

Comment: The reason `interp1` doesn't do anything in your example is that `tv` is exactly the same as `t`.